# Configure Date Format of React Input Date-type

Tags: date, input, momentjs, locale, reactstrap

I have an `<Input/>` from reactstrap that accepts date. I'm using moment.js to parse my date. Although I want the format of the dates to be localized.

This is my code:

```
<Input
   bsSize="lg"
   type="date"
   name="date"
   value={moment(this.state.birthDate).locale('en').format("LLLL")}
   onChange={this.handleBirthDateChange}
/>
```

Although when I try to select my date input, it doesn't accept the date chosen.

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: using this {moment(this.state.birthDate).locale('en').format("LLLL")} wont accept the date chosen on my input

Comment: would you post the handleBirthDateChange as well?

Answer (score 1):

Moment will be an object, you'd need to format it to the ISO standard string which is the HTML's date type

Try this `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-mclaren-tuqz0

This might help you get started

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import moment from 'moment'
import {Input} from 'reactstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      birthDate: moment()
        .locale('en')
        .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    }
  }
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({birthDate: e.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    let {birthDate} = this.state
    return (
      <>
        <Input
          bsSize="lg"
          type="date"
          name="date"
          value={birthDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```